# php preg_match помогите с выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно достать число от 4-6 символом из строки, что бы после неё не стояло через любое кол-во пробелов "руб" или "руб." Делаю так:

```
$Pattern = "/([\d]{4,6})(?!\s*rub\.?)/";
```

Из строки без "руб" вырезает нормально. В строке где есть "руб", всё равно ловит число, и отъедает последнею цифру.
Помогите исправить.

Сделал так:

```
if (preg_match($Pattern, /*$message->body*/
                    "Ваш номер 7854 руб. 1452 руб Долг 341328 руб", $matches) === 1) {

    echo "Count of matches: ".count($matches)."\n";
    var_dump($matches);
    //$Code = $matches[0];
    //echo "Code is:".$Code . "\n";
```

}

Найти ничего не должен. Но результат такой:

```
Count of matches: 1
```

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "34132"
}

Comment: Можете предоставить несколько исходных строк для теста?

Comment: Ваша задолженность 1000 руб. Скорость интернета ограничена до пополнения счета. Уникальный номер для оплаты 12345

10444 - ваш код для активации обещанного платежа на сумму 100 руб.
Недостаточно средств для оплаты услуг. Пополните ваш счет на сумму 1000 руб в течении 3 дней. 12345 - ваш уникальный номер для оплаты .

Comment: Еще один мего провайдер?))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//$str = 'Ваша задолженность 1000руб. Скорость интернета ограничена до пополнения счета. Уникальный номер для оплаты 12345 10444 - ваш код для активации обещанного платежа на сумму 100 руб.';

$str = 'Ваш номер 7854 руб. 1452 руб Долг 341328 руб';

$patt = '~\b\d{4,6}\b(?!\s*руб\.?)~';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '12345' (length=5)
      1 => string '10444' (length=5)
```

Comment: Можно немного дополнить регулярку, что бы искался `руб` или `rub` `([\d]{4,6})(?!\s*(rub|руб)\.?)`

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Сделал по вашему шаблону. Но в случае отсутствия такого числа вообще, всё равно получаю одно значение

Comment: @Morph я подкорректировал свой ответ.

Comment: Всё так. Странно, но я думал что \b работает только для буквенных символом. Это меня запутало.